# Devise Login Form on another page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I wish to add a devise login form to my home page (model called home)

I have found this but stuck where to put certain bits and work!

http://pupeno.com/2010/08/29/show-a-devise-log-in-form-in-another-page/

```
<h2>Sign in</h2>

<% form_for resource_name, resource, :url => session_path(resource_name) do |f| -%>
  <p><%= f.label :email %></p>
  <p><%= f.text_field :email %></p>

  <p><%= f.label :password %></p>
  <p><%= f.password_field :password %></p>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <p><%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me %></p>
  <% end -%>

  <p><%= f.submit "Sign in" %></p>
<% end -%>

<%= render :partial => "shared/devise_links" %>
```

and (no idea where to put)

```
module ContentHelper
  def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
end
```

My devise is set up as 'members' so any help would be great :) Cheers

Comment: Can you try putting ContentHelper in app/helpers and renaming "User" to "Member" and ":user" to ":member"

Comment: @JesseWolgamott I get: wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)
on line 12: <% form_for resource_name, resource, :url => session_path(resource_name) do |f| -%>

Comment: Got it working. Changed to 

`<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>` 

:)

Cheers @JesseWolgamott