# Devise form within different view "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

So I am trying to do pretty much the same thing as [Devise form within a different controller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4081744/1769385)

exactly [Devise Login Form on another page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14712299/1769385)

I have a helper module that has

```
def resource_name
  :user
end

def resource
  @resource ||= User.new
end

def devise_mapping
  @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
end
```

but I am getting **undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass** on the line

```
<%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>
```

I put <% raise resource.inspect %> in views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb

and I got RuntimeError in Home#index  **#User not initialized**

```
<h2>Sign in</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => user_session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <% raise resource.inspect %>
  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
  <div><%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me %></div>
  <% end -%>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign in" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

and I also tried this for the helper module

```
def resource_name
  :user
end

def resource
  @resource = User.new
end

def devise_mapping
  @devise_mapping = Devise.mappings[:user]
end
```

In Home#index, I have the following

```
<div class="loginform" id="login">
  <%= render :file => "devise/sessions/new" %>
</div>
```

The error "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" will be gone if views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb edits to be

```
<%= form_for(:user, :as => @user, :url => user_session_path(@user)) do |f| %>
```

but if put <% raise resource.inspect %> back in views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb

will still get #User not initialized>

In user.rb

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

In application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  helper :all
end
```

using 'rails', '3.2.11'

I am not sure why the helper module doesn't work the way it supposes be for resource. Can anyone help me to understand why? and why getting "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you have `@User` and not `@user` (difference is on the case of the letter `u`) in the erb file ? Usually instance variables starts with lower case, might be a typo

Comment: I wan just trying it out. @user won't give the error either. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: if somehow your source code is on github, could you give the URL of the repo ? I find it easier to fix that kind of problem by directly touching the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this line

```
<%= form_for(:user, :as => @user, :url => user_session_path(@user)) do |f| %>
```

should be

```
<%= form_for(@user, :as => :user, :url => user_session_path(@user)) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Oh, Right! I messed up the variables. <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => user_session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %> should be <%= form_for(resource_name, :as => resource, :url => user_session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %> Lovely, thank you!